# how to configure Postfix to send more emails per hour than the default

Tags: postfix-mta

My postfix only let me send only 3600 email in an hour ( from which i conclude that there is 1s delay between each email ) while I want to send double that number .. I looked in the postfix configuration .Is there any parameters that i can change to send more than 3600 email in an hour ?
this is the output of `postconf -n`

```
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
bounce_queue_lifetime = 1d
command_directory = /usr/sbin
config_directory = /etc/postfix
daemon_directory = /usr/libexec/postfix
data_directory = /var/lib/postfix
debug_peer_level = 2
default_destination_concurrency_limit = 5
default_destination_rate_delay = 0s
html_directory = no
inet_interfaces = all
inet_protocols = ipv4
initial_destination_concurrency = 2
lmtp_destination_rate_delay = 0s
local_destination_rate_delay = 0s
mail_owner = postfix
mailq_path = /usr/bin/mailq.postfix
manpage_directory = /usr/share/man
maximal_queue_lifetime = 1d
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain, localhost, $mydomain
mydomain = example.com
myhostname = server01.example.com
myorigin = $mydomain
newaliases_path = /usr/bin/newaliases.postfix
qmgr_message_recipient_limit = 10000
queue_directory = /var/spool/postfix
readme_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.5.6/README_FILES
relay_destination_rate_delay = 0s
sample_directory = /usr/share/doc/postfix-2.5.6/samples
sendmail_path = /usr/sbin/sendmail.postfix
setgid_group = postdrop
smtp_bind_address = xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
smtp_destination_rate_delay = 0s
smtp_generic_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/generic
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name
smtpd_client_restrictions = check_client_access hash:/etc/postfix/access
unknown_local_recipient_reject_code = 550
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
virtual_destination_rate_delay = 0s
```

Comment: Somehow I'm less than enthused about the implications of *why* somebody would want to send more than one email per second (i.e., it sounds a lot like sending spam), but regardless of that, configuring a server doesn't seem to be a programming-related problem.

Comment: @Jerry Coffin: Here's a potential *why* (no idea if this is any relation to the OP's reason):  I used to work for a financial services firm; we offered automatic email alerts to clients based on conditions they could specify.  So when a market crossed some boundary (e.g., DOW > 10k, oil > 60 USD/bbl, etc) we would trigger thousands of emails.  All of which were going to customers who'd complain if it arrived >5 minutes post-event.

Answer (score 4):

see this,

you can play around with

default_recipient_limit
qmgr_message_recipient_limit
default_destination_rate_delay

The default amount of delay that is inserted between individual deliveries to the same destination; with per-destination recipient limit > 1, a destination is a domain, otherwise it is a recipient.

To enable the delay, specify a non-zero time value (an integral value plus an optional one-letter suffix that specifies the time unit).

Time units: s (seconds), m (minutes), h (hours), d (days), w (weeks). The default time unit is s (seconds).

NOTE: the delay is enforced by the queue manager. The delay timer state does not survive "postfix reload" or "postfix stop".

Use transport_destination_rate_delay to specify a transport-specific override, where transport is the master.cf name of the message delivery transport.

This feature is available in Postfix 2.5 and later.
http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html